# Adding a network printer via link

Tags: networking, printing, installation

I am trying to install a printer by just giving users a link.

I need to make a website were users will be able to click on hyperlink that will install a network printer for them.

The solution I have runs VB script and it requires ActiveX what makes confuses users.

The Solution example...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<script type="text/vbscript">
function AddP(pName)
msgbox "Adding..."
Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection pName
msgbox "The printer is added!"
end function
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div>
    <a href='#' language="vbscript" onclick="AddP('PRINTER LOCATION')">Add printer</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The solution works on Win 7 32 bit with IE8.

Is there any other solution available for this, can I use just HTML and JavaScript to solve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3293570/1350424

Comment: users are allowed to install printers..no admin rights are needed